# Действия на каждый find()

Tags: jquery

Как при таком find, если эментов множество, то записать текст каждого элемента в массив?

```
start = $('#drop').find('.price').text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотреть можно [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7vucN/1/).

```
var els = $('#drop').find('.price');
var arr = els.map(function(i,el){
    return $(el).text();
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: а можно спросить, что делает .get() на конце?

Comment: Что он делает "на конце" - я не знаю )) А в конце - возвращает массив. ;)

Comment: Правильно будет так:$('.price', '#drop').map(function(i,el){ return $(this).text(); }).toArray(); 
Вызывая .get() пы получаете не массив, а jQuery collection.

Comment: @RubaXa, именно массив. Ну, вы то уж могли бы [почитать мануал][1]?

> Without a parameter, .get() returns an array 

Но как альтернатива *.toArray();* - тоже нормально.

   [1]:http://api.jquery.com/get/#get

Comment: Хм, вы правы, как обычно у jQuery кучу методов, делающий одно и тоже, но toArray более семантически :]

Comment: @RubaXa, однако, ваше утверждение не лишено смысла в том случае, если бы мы работали с DOM-объектами. Результат действительно не совсем похоже на массив в привычном понимании.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="drop">
    <div class="price">125</div>    
    <div class="price">105</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
start = Array();
$.each($('#drop').find('.price'), function(){
    start.push($(this).text());
});
document.write(start[0]);
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку Cannot call method 'push' of undefined